# Changing variable values inside movieclips in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, movieclip

Is it possible? If so, how?

Let's say I have a movieclip in the main timeline named `mc_1` and inside this movieclip I have another movieclip named `mc_2` that has a variable called `numberExample`.

What I am trying to do is change `numberExample` values from the main timeline itself.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `mc1.mc2.numberExample`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace

```
 trace(mc_1.mc_2.numberExample);
```

or change it like this:

```
mc_1.mc_2.numberExample=3;
```